# How to move a kineticjs circle?

Tags: kineticjs, geometry

1)
Why obj.setX(newx) does not move my kineticjs circles?

I am now using obj.transitionTo function calls.

2) Why transitionTo moves my circle even without layer.drawScene ?

setRadius is also not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 you have to call layer.draw to see result.

2 when you are using transitionTo draw function are calling automatically.

Comment: Now it works !! I used transitionTo over month ! How stupid a human person can be? But it worked just fine..